# htaccess not working due to lack of knowledge

Tags: .htaccess

So I want to send three variables (separated by slashes) to my index.php but I can't get it working, I'm a leek with htaccess.

My base url is localhost:8888/smbo/

And I have this code which does not work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /smbo/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1&idTwo=$2&idThree=$3
</IfModule>
```

Who can help me?

Comment: Have you enabled the `mod_rewrite`? If you're working on something like WAMP it's not enabled by default when you install it. If yes, then go click on WAMP's icon in system tray and then go to this menu: `Apache -> Apache modules -> rewrite_moudle`. Restart the WAMP and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /smbo/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?id=$1&idTwo=$2&idThree=$3
```